# Use Stringr to select all middle words, leaving out the first and last word

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have a list of full names that I am trying to split into first name, last name and then all middle names.

```
name <- c('James Freddy Peter','James Peter','James Freddy Freddy Peter', 'James Freddy Samuel Freddy Peter')
```

I have managed to select the first name:

```
firstName <- gsub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", name)
```

And the last name

```
lastName <- gsub("^.* ([[:alnum:]]+)$", '\\1', name)
```

But Im stuck on how to select everything else. All the examples I have seen have used some other delimiter to separate by (i.e. between "-" and "-"). I am also aware that it seems to be bad practice to select everything except a given pattern. It also seems redundant to go through, separate out a string by spaces and select by position. Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
middle <- gsub("^\\S+\\s*|\\s*\\S+$", "", name)
# => [1] "Freddy"  ""  "Freddy Freddy"  "Freddy Samuel Freddy"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/eYpDFo) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hMJq0U/1).

**Details**

- `^\S+\s*` - start of string (`^`), one or more nonwhitespace chars (`\S+`) and then 0+ whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `\s*\S+$` - 0+ whitespace chars, one or more nonwhitespace chars (`\S+`) and then end of string (`$`).

Using `stringr`, you may leverage `str_match`:

```
> str_match(name, '^(\\S+)\\s*(.*?)\\s*(\\S+)$')[,-1]
     [,1]    [,2]                   [,3]   
[1,] "James" "Freddy"               "Peter"
[2,] "James" ""                     "Peter"
[3,] "James" "Freddy Freddy"        "Peter"
[4,] "James" "Freddy Samuel Freddy" "Peter"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hMJq0U/2), all the parts are *captured* into the three groups. `.*?` matches any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (to trim the whitespace before the last "word").

Comment: Since the OP mentions `stringr`, also this: `str_extract(name, "(?<=\\s)[\\w\\s]+(?=\\s)")`?

Comment: @Dunois Ok, I added another stringr solution.